# Laravel 5.3 global scope dies when executing additional query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to add a global scope to a lot of models (I'm putting it into a trait) which will check if `\Session::has('admin')` and if it does it will query the 'admins' table, get the 'main_website' this admin belongs to and only show the results that belong to this website.

The problem is that the global scope dies after I start executing another query and I get error 500 with nothing in my logs.

Here is the trait:

```
trait MainWebsitable {

    public static function bootMainWebsitable()
    {
        static::addGlobalScope(new MainWebsitableScope);
    }

    public function mainWebsites()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(MainWebsite::class, 'main_websitable');
    }

    public function scopeByWebsiteId($query, $id)
    {
        return $query->whereHas('mainWebsites', function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('id', $id);
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the global scope:

```
class MainWebsitableScope implements Scope {
    public function apply(Builder $builder, Model $model) {
        if(\Session::has('admin')) {
            $adminId    = \Session::get('admin');
            $admin      = Admin::find($adminId);
            $website    = $admin->mainWebsites->first();
            if(isset($website)) {
                $builder->byWebsiteId($website->id);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried putting `dd(\Session::get('admin'))` after first if and it successfully returns the value saved in session. Then I've tried putting dd($admin) after `Admin::find($adminId)` and it returns the same 500 error as if I didn't have dd(). I've also tried doing another query (not querying the Admin model, but some other table) in that place and the same thing happens - 500 error with no explanation.

Here are the nginx logs: http://pastebin.com/1EX4aRvV

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have debug mode disabled?  Not a good idea when developing.  Laravel maintains an error log in storages/logs.

Comment: I dont. It's enabled. I get meaningful errors everywhere else. Edit: I've just tried causing a simple namespace error (mistyped a namespace), to prove it  and it does indeed throw a nice Laravel "FatalThrowableError in MainWebsitableScope.php line 15:..."

Comment: And your Laravel log and web server log don't contain any info?  (How are you running the web server?  Are you using artisan serve?)

Comment: I'm running homestead on vagrant. I've never really looked at any of those logs (I don't even know where they are stored). I will google it and get back to you.

Comment: Here are the logs (will update the question as well). http://pastebin.com/1EX4aRvV

Comment: Okay, so I've figured it out. I had the same trait in the Admin model, which brought me to infinite nesting problem. The model I was updating had the trait => the trait looked at Admin model to get his main website => the admin had the trait, so it looked at admin model again .. and again and again until it decided to die.